# Возвращение ссылки функцией

Tags: c++

Есть код:

```
int x;
int& setx();
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    setx() = 92;
    cout << "x =" << x << endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
int& setx() {
    return x; // возвращает значение, которое будет изменено
}
```

Почему без знака амперсанда он не пашет? Типо, только тип возвращаемоо значения(т.е. ссылка) может поменять переменную?

Comment: Понятия "не пашет" на SO нет. Потрудитесь выражаться яснее. "только тип возвращаемоо значения(т.е. ссылка) может поменять переменную?" - совершенно не ясно, что вы тут хотите сказать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если убрать "знак &", т.е. ссылку, то возвращаемое значение ...

1. ... никак не будет связано с оригинальной переменной `x`. Даже если вы как-то его поменяете, то на переменную `x` это никакого влияния не окажет.

   (Невозможно поменять возвращаемое значение типа `int`, но это может быть возможно для других возвращаемых типов, например `std::string`)
2. ... не будет являться lvalue, т.е. присваивать ему чего-либо при помощи встроенного оператора присваивания будет нельзя.

Что вы имеете в виду под "не пашет" из вашего вопроса не ясно.